# how can i get the name of the new created user in the return message?

Tags: python, json, api, flask, return

what do i have to do that the  new created User will appear in the message?

```
 @anrufe.route('/createuser', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        name = data['name']
        password = data['password']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO User(name,password) VALUES(%s, %s)",
                        (name, password))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()


        return jsonify({'message' : 'New user created'})

    return render_template('indexuser.html')
```

in the line return jsonify....

Comment: `'New user created: ' + name`…!?

Comment: @deceze but he should be sure that his data is inserted correctly without any exception

Comment: @Ahmed Not sure what possible exception you're alluding to here.

Comment: Just check my answer now

Comment: @Ahmed Sure, OP *should* handle exceptions, but that's pretty irrelevant to concatenating the name to the return value…

Comment: If you can improve it, do it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213702/discussion-between-ahmed-rebai-and-deceze).

Answer (score -1):

I just edited your code and adding how to handle Mysql exceptions

```
@anrufe.route('/createuser', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def create_user():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.form
            name = data['name']
            password = data['password']
            try :
                cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO User(name,password) VALUES(%s, %s)",
                                    (name, password))
                mysql.connection.commit()

                return jsonify({'message' : 'New User'+name +'Created!})

            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print(err)
            print("Error Code:", err.errno)
            print("SQLSTATE", err.sqlstate)
            print("Message", err.msg)

                cursor.close()
                db.close()
```

Comment: can you tell what i have to do if i want an error if the name already exist ?

Comment: It's related to you, how you want to implement it, and if you want to get an error about exciting value of name you should implement it in your database